# The name `CrossPlatformInput' does not exist in the current context

Tags: unity-game-engine

this is my first time using Unity so please bear with me. I created a very basic setup for my game. A ground plane, a third person controller with a main camera, a Material for the ground plane, some obstacles and a lightning source. Now the last thing I wanted to add before working on some actual gameplay was a skybox. Please note that at this point, I could play and everything was working flawlessly.

I searched the asset store for a free skybox and found this one: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/18353

Upon adding it, I immediately got a compiler error:

> The name `CrossPlatformInput' does not exist in the current context",
>   and "The type or namespace name 'CrossPlatformInput' does not exist in
>   the namespace 'UnitySampleAssets', are you missing an assembly
>   reference?.

At lines in scripts that were already there before I added the skybox. I figured something must be wrong with the skybox, so I deleted it from the project, however the errors did not go with it, in fact they still persist! I've tried reimporting all of my assets already (as suggested by similiar posts on this forum), including the Standard Assets folder which houses CrossPlatformInput, which did nothing to solve my problem.

Does anybody know what could have caused this? Since I deleted the skybox, how could it possibly still affect my project?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download [Unity Standard Asset](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/32351) and import CrossPlatformInput. The free skybox  depends on it to work. In your project tab, **Import Package** -> **CrossPlatformInput**.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, this worked flawlessly!